# clone() not working (for me)

Tags: jquery

User enters pairs of values. I need to replicate the last set and renumber their ids. The function below runs, but the new div doesn't appear. I'm off in the weeds somewhere... thanks for help!

```
    $('#addparm').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var maxSeq = $('#maxseq').attr("seq");
        var lastDiv = $('#pct[' + maxSeq + ']').parent();
        $('#maxseq').attr("seq", ++maxSeq);
        var newDiv = $(lastDiv).clone(true);
        $(lastDiv).after(newDiv);
        $(newDiv).fadeIn('slow');
    });
```

here's the HTML:

```
    ... 
    <div id="bkp[8]">
        <input seq="8" id="pct[8]" name="pct" type="text" value="0.28" />
        <input seq="8" id="amt[8]" name="amt" type="text" value="43.2" />
        <input seq="8" id="use[8]" name="use" type="hidden" value="yes" />
    </div> 

    <div id="bkp[9]">
        <input seq="9" id="pct[9]" name="pct" type="text" value="0.31" />
        <input seq="9" id="amt[9]" name="amt" type="text" value="41.4" />
        <input seq="9" id="use[9]" name="use" type="hidden" value="yes" />
    </div> 
<input type="hidden" id="maxseq" seq="9" />
<a id="addparm" href="javascript:void(0)">Add</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clone is working fine, but your selector is not finding anything on which to operate.

Per the [HTML specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2), you cannot use square brackets in an element's ID. Further, your selectors which look for elements with IDs that have square brackets are not matching what you think they are.

The selector:

```
#foo[5]
```

Does not match an element with ID `foo[5]`, rather it looks for an [element with ID `foo`](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) and an [attribute named `5`](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/).

This means that `lastDiv` is holding an empty jQuery collection, so nothing gets cloned and nothing gets appended.

The solution is to either escape the square brackets in your selectors while maintaining the improper ID attr values (not recommended), or modify your ID values to meet the specs and adjust your code to the new ID format.

Comment: This is true. Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/C2R8D/  I changed the id of the element in question to remove square brackets and made the same change in the jQuery selector.

Comment: Here is proof that you **can** keep your ids as-is. Just escape the square brackets with two backslashes in your jQuery selector.http://jsfiddle.net/8REPj/  However, @JAAulde is correct that the HTML4 spec says this is not a legal ID, so it is probably adviseable to change the ID format.

Comment: Yes, with escaped selectors you can use some items in your selectors which are better left out of the mix. It would better to adjust the syntax and methodologies, IMO.

Comment: Thanks guys, you rock. I thought I *had* to have brackets in the id in order to get asp mvc to recognize the collection of values as an array. It does this, but maybe for different reasons than I thought.

Comment: @EricNelson generally it's the `name` attr which would have square brackets to cause a set of elements to be a collection--though I don't know anything about ASP. This is an odd thing, though, because `name` attrs are also considered name tokens and, therefore, should not have square brackets on them. Glad this info helped.